# The program runs once when button is clicked, and then nothing

Tags: python, tkinter

The code when i run it works only once when i press the button, but after that when i press the button again nothing happens. please i am novice so bear with me
below is my code:

```
from Tkinter import*
import random

class Love:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Love Calculator")
        window.geometry("300x180")

        frame1 = Frame(window)
        frame1.pack()
        self.lbl = Label(frame1, fg="white", bg = "blue",            text = "Love is Pure" )
        self.lbl2= Label(frame1, fg="White", bg = "red", width="50", text = "are you meant for one another")
        self.lbl3= Label(frame1, fg="white", bg = "green",           text = "Let FIND OUT!!" )
        self.lbl.pack()
        self.lbl2.pack()
        self.lbl3.pack()

        frame2 = Frame(window)
        frame2.pack()
        label  = Label(frame2, text = "Your Name")
        label2 = Label(frame2, text = "Your Lovers name")

        self.msg = StringVar()
        entry1 = Entry(frame2, textvariable = self.msg)

        self.out = StringVar()
        entry2 = Entry(frame2, textvariable = self.out)

        btCalculate=Button(frame2, command=self.processButton, text="Calculate" )
        btClear=Button(    frame2, command=self.clear_textbox, text="Try Another Name" )

        label.grid(       row=1,column=1)          # .GUI-geometry
        label2.grid(      row=2,column=1)
        entry1.grid(      row=1,column=2)
        entry2.grid(      row=2,column=2)
        btCalculate.grid( row=6,column=6,sticky=E)
        btClear.grid(     row=6,column=5)

        window.mainloop()                          # .GUI-control-loop

    def clear_textbox(self,):                      # .CMD callbackHANDLER
        entry1.delete(0, END)
        entry2.delete(0, END)

    def processButton(self):                       # .CMD callbackHANDLER
        example = [ 'Enter a name','are lovers','are admirers','are suppose to marry','are enemies','are secrete lovers','OMG could this be love','Till death do you apart','are crazy lovers','are romantic overs','O feeli wo!','are friends','are lovers','are admirers','are suppose to marry','are enemies','are secrete lovers','Eii OMG could this be love','Till death do you apart','crazy lovers','romantic lovers','O feeli wo!', 'are friends','are lovers','are admirers','are suppose to marry','are enemies','are secrete lovers','OMG, could this be love','Till death do you apart','are crazy lovers','are romantic lovers','O feeli wo!','are friends','are lovers','are admirers','are suppose to marry','are enemies','are secrete lovers','OMG could this be love','Till death do you apart','are crazy lovers','are romantic lovers','O feeli wo!','are friends','are lovers','are admirers','are suppose to marry','are enemies','are secrete lovers','Eii OMG could this be love','Till death do you apart','crazy lovers','romantic lovers','O feeli wo!','are friends','are lovers','are admirers','are suppose to marry','are enemies','are secrete lovers','OMG, could this be love','Till death do you apart','are crazy lovers','are romantic lovers','O feeli wo!','are friends','are lovers','are admirers','are suppose to marry','are enemies','are secrete lovers','OMG could this be love','Till death do you apart','are crazy lovers','are romantic lovers','O feeli wo!','are friends','are lovers','are admirers','are suppose to marry','are enemies','are secrete lovers','Eii OMG could this be love','Till death do you apart','crazy lovers','romantic lovers','O feeli wo!','are friends','are lovers','are admirers','are suppose to marry','are enemies','are secrete lovers','OMG, could this be love','Till death do you apart','are crazy lovers','are romantic lovers','O feeli wo!']
        brief   = [ 'Enter a name','Lovers, who will not allow anything to come between them no matter what,They will eventually get married','They might me admirers although, buh one of them is hiding some emotions, that will one day break his or her heart','Thier marriage will endure and truimph over every trouble, Always together','They are not actually enemies buh, due to one act or a reason they dont wanna be friends for now, buh i bet one day, friendship will be their portion','The Guy is afraid to make a step, the girl think i might be too cheap, they end up leaving their burning desires to the wind, buh hey one day they might make it together in marriage','It depends it might be love, it could also be illusions, so hey becareful','They are Almost at verge of marriage buh could also be very good friends till death do them apart','Crazy as it may seem, they really love each other and nothing will stop them','This guys are romantically bonded, they have sexual desires for each other, buh thats not very helthy, Because it always leads to nothing',' Just like each other and can really be fun, cause they almost like admirers','their friendship will thrive through the storms of life till eternity','Lovers, who will not allow anything to come between them no matter what,They will eventually get married','They might me admirers although, buh one of them is hiding some emotions, that will one day break his or her heart','Thier marriage will endure and truimph over every trouble, Always together','They are not actually enemies buh, due to one act or a reason they dont wanna be friends for now, buh i bet one day, friendship will be their portion','The Guy is afraid to make a step, the girl think i might be too cheap,they end up leaving their burning desires to the wind, buh hey one day they might make it together in marriage','It depends it might be love, it could also be illusions, so hey becareful','They are Almost at verge of marriage buh could also be very good friends till death do them apart','Crazy as it may seem, they really love each other and nothing will stop them','This guys are romantically bonded, they have sexual desires for each other, buh thats not very helthy, Because it always leads to nothing',' Just like each other and can really be fun, cause they almost like admirers','their friendship will thrive through the storms of life till eternity','Lovers, who will not allow anything to come between them no matter what,They will eventually get married','They might me admirers although, buh one of them is hiding some emotions, that will one day break his or her heart','Thier marriage will endure and truimph over every trouble, Always together','They are not actually enemies buh, due to one act or a reason they dont wanna be friends for now, buh i bet one day, friendship will be their portion','The Guy is afraid to make a step, the girl think i might be too cheap,they end up leaving their burning desires to the wind, buh hey one day they might make it together in marriage','It depends it might be love, it could also be illusions, so hey becareful','They are Almost at verge of marriage buh could also be very good friends till death do them apart','Crazy as it may seem, they really love each other and nothing will stop them','This guys are romantically bonded, they have sexual desires for each other, buh thats not very helthy, Because it always leads to nothing',' Just like each other and can really be fun, cause they almost like admirers','their friendship will thrive through the storms of life till eternity','Lovers, who will not allow anything to come between them no matter what,They will eventually get married','They might me admirers although, buh one of them is hiding some emotions, that will one day break his or her heart','Thier marriage will endure and truimph over every trouble, Always together','They are not actually enemies buh, due to one act or a reason they dont wanna be friends for now, buh i bet one day, friendship will be their portion','The Guy is afraid to make a step, the girl think i might be too cheap, they end up leaving their burning desires to the wind, buh hey one day they might make it together in marriage','It depends it might be love, it could also be illusions, so hey becareful','They are Almost at verge of marriage buh could also be very good friends till death do them apart','Crazy as it may seem, they really love each other and nothing will stop them','This guys are romantically bonded, they have sexual desires for each other, buh thats not very helthy, Because it always leads to nothing',' Just like each other and can really be fun, cause they almost like admirers','their friendship will thrive through the storms of life till eternity','Lovers, who will not allow anything to come between them no matter what,They will eventually get married','They might me admirers although, buh one of them is hiding some emotions, that will one day break his or her heart','Thier marriage will endure and truimph over every trouble, Always together','They are not actually enemies buh, due to one act or a reason they dont wanna be friends for now, buh i bet one day, friendship will be their portion','The Guy is afraid to make a step, the girl think i might be too cheap,they end up leaving their burning desires to the wind, buh hey one day they might make it together in marriage','It depends it might be love, it could also be illusions, so hey becareful','They are Almost at verge of marriage buh could also be very good friends till death do them apart','Crazy as it may seem, they really love each other and nothing will stop them','This guys are romantically bonded, they have sexual desires for each other, buh thats not very helthy, Because it always leads to nothing',' Just like each other and can really be fun, cause they almost like admirers','their friendship will thrive through the storms of life till eternity','Lovers, who will not allow anything to come between them no matter what,They will eventually get married','They might me admirers although, buh one of them is hiding some emotions, that will one day break his or her heart','Thier marriage will endure and truimph over every trouble, Always together','They are not actually enemies buh, due to one act or a reason they dont wanna be friends for now, buh i bet one day, friendship will be their portion','The Guy is afraid to make a step, the girl think i might be too cheap,they end up leaving their burning desires to the wind, buh hey one day they might make it together in marriage','It depends it might be love, it could also be illusions, so hey becareful','They are Almost at verge of marriage buh could also be very good friends till death do them apart','Crazy as it may seem, they really love each other and nothing will stop them','This guys are romantically bonded, they have sexual desires for each other, buh thats not very helthy, Because it always leads to nothing',' Just like each other and can really be fun, cause they almost like admirers','their friendship will thrive through the storms of life till eternity','Lovers, who will not allow anything to come between them no matter what,They will eventually get married','They might me admirers although, buh one of them is hiding some emotions, that will one day break his or her heart','Thier marriage will endure and truimph over every trouble, Always together','They are not actually enemies buh, due to one act or a reason they dont wanna be friends for now, buh i bet one day, friendship will be their portion','The Guy is afraid to make a step, the girl think i might be too cheap, they end up leaving their burning desires to the wind, buh hey one day they might make it together in marriage','It depends it might be love, it could also be illusions, so hey becareful','They are Almost at verge of marriage buh could also be very good friends till death do them apart','Crazy as it may seem, they really love each other and nothing will stop them','This guys are romantically bonded, they have sexual desires for each other, buh thats not very helthy, Because it always leads to nothing',' Just like each other and can really be fun, cause they almost like admirers','their friendship will thrive through the storms of life till eternity','Lovers, who will not allow anything to come between them no matter what,They will eventually get married','They might me admirers although, buh one of them is hiding some emotions, that will one day break his or her heart','Thier marriage will endure and truimph over every trouble, Always together','They are not actually enemies buh, due to one act or a reason they dont wanna be friends for now, buh i bet one day, friendship will be their portion','The Guy is afraid to make a step, the girl think i might be too cheap,they end up leaving their burning desires to the wind, buh hey one day they might make it together in marriage','It depends it might be love, it could also be illusions, so hey becareful','They are Almost at verge of marriage buh could also be very good friends till death do them apart','Crazy as it may seem, they really love each other and nothing will stop them','This guys are romantically bonded, they have sexual desires for each other, buh thats not very helthy, Because it always leads to nothing',' Just like each other and can really be fun, cause they almost like admirers','their friendship will thrive through the storms of life till eternity','Lovers, who will not allow anything to come between them no matter what,They will eventually get married','They might me admirers although, buh one of them is hiding some emotions, that will one day break his or her heart','Thier marriage will endure and truimph over every trouble, Always together','They are not actually enemies buh, due to one act or a reason they dont wanna be friends for now, buh i bet one day, friendship will be their portion','The Guy is afraid to make a step, the girl think i might be too cheap,they end up leaving their burning desires to the wind, buh hey one day they might make it together in marriage','It depends it might be love, it could also be illusions, so hey becareful','They are Almost at verge of marriage buh could also be very good friends till death do them apart','Crazy as it may seem, they really love each other and nothing will stop them','This guys are romantically bonded, they have sexual desires for each other, buh thats not very helthy, Because it always leads to nothing',' Just like each other and can really be fun, cause they almost like admirers']
                                                   # .SET <brief> a smarter way ( original post was a longest list on screen as an example "ever-seen", be a bit more polite, sir
        self.out   = str(self.out)
        self.msg   = str(self.msg)
        Len1       = len(self.out)
        Len2       = len(self.msg)
        Len        = (Len2+Len1)-3
        self.out   = example[Len]
        self.msg   = brief[Len]
        Percentage = "You're",random.randint(20,100),"% in love"

        Percentage = str(Percentage)
        self.lbl[ "text"]="You are",self.out
        self.lbl2["text"]= self.msg
        self.lbl3["text"]= Percentage

        return;


Love()
```

Comment: You should start with the way you use `self.msg` and `self.out`. These are `StringVar`s, so you can change them by using `self.msg.set('something')`, and retrieve their info using `self.msg.get()`. So to clear them use `self.msg.set('')` and to use them to calculate Len1 use `Len1 = len(self.out.get())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is running multiple times, according to my tests. The problem appears to be that you're calculating Len to be 11 the first time you run it, then 77 every time after that. This is because you're calculating Len1 and Len2 from the MESSAGE boxes, not from the ENTRY boxes, and message 11 (friendship strive through storms of eternity) is EXACTLY the right number of letters to make it point to itself when you calculate again.

You can fix this by replacing

```
    self.out=str(self.out)
    self.msg=str(self.msg)
    Len1 = len(self.out)
    Len2 =len(self.msg)
```

with

```
    entry1str=self.entry1.get()
    entry2str=self.entry2.get()
    Len1 = len(entry1str)
    Len2 =len(entry2str)
```

Also, while I'm here, you need to use self.entry1 and self.entry2 in most of the places you've used entry1 and entry2, otherwise the boxes don't clear properly.

Hope that helps!